# Can't fully correct encoding issue from website

Tags: c#, character-encoding, web-scraping

I'm developing a web scraper for a soccer site. There is an issue when pulling in names from various countries (which, obviously, have various characters). I've worked out a method to correct some of it, but it's not catching Turkish or anything else. Here is what I have so far:

```
private String formatMe(String sF)
    {
      String myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sF))
         .Replace("Ã©", "é")
         .Replace("Ã¡", "á")
         .Replace("Ã­", "í")
         .Replace("Ã³", "ó");

      return myString;

    }//END FORMAT
```

Here's [an example of a site I would pull from](http://us.soccerway.com/matches/2015/04/04/england/premier-league/arsenal-fc/liverpool-fc/1704095/).

Is there anyway I can just fix the encoding from the site in one fell swoop?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Characters are coming in all wonky. For instance M. Özil is coming in as M. Ã–zil.